# Insert into vector with conditional iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Say I have a `vector` with various entries, which I want to insert into another vector, while leaving out entries that satisfy a condition.

For example, I want to insert a vector while leaving out all three's.

```
{1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3} -> { /* previous content, */ 1, 2, 4, 5}
```

What I came up with so far uses `std::partition`, which does not preserve the relative order and rearranges the source vector.

```
std::vector<int> source({1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3});
std::vector<int> target;

auto partition = std::partition(std::begin(source),
                   std::end(source), [](const auto& a) { return a == 3; });
target.insert(std::begin(target), partition, std::end(source));
```

**What I am looking for** is more of an iterator that checks a condition and moves on if the condition is not satisfied. Something like this:

```
target.insert(std::begin(target),
              conditional_begin(source, [](const auto& a) { return a != 3; }),
              conditional_end(source));
```

I suppose a `conditional_end` function would be necessary, since `std::end` would return a different iterator type than `conditional_begin`.

Maybe I have overlooked something, so my **questions** are:

- Does the standard library provide something similar?
- Is there a different easy way to achieve my goal?
- Is there an easy way to implement the conditional iterator functionality?

Comment: Have you had a look at `std::copy_if`?

Comment: No, haven't considered that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is there a different easy way to achieve my goal?

Yes, the standard already has this functionality built in.  The function you are looking for is [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
std::vector<int> source({1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3});
std::vector<int> target;

std::copy_if(source.begin(), 
             source.end(), 
             std::back_inserter(target), [](auto val){ return val != 3; });
```

Here, `std::back_inserter(target)`, will call `push_back` on `target` for each element that the predicate returns `true`.

Comment: The `back_inserter` here could cause multiple allocations on `target` which might not be optimal for performance critical code.

Comment: @ChrisDrew True, but if you don't know how many elements will be copied you either have to guess or let it geometrically grow.

Comment: Or you can work out how many elements will be copied first, either by counting them, or filtering them in place before inserting them. Which may (or may not) be faster, you would have to measure. I just think it is worth being aware of.

Comment: How much to reserve and to reserve at all is very dependent on the context in which the code is called.

Comment: fwiw the `std::vector::insert` overload that takes two forward iterators effectively counts and reserves before inserting.

Comment: @ChrisDrew To use vector::insert with a pair of iterators, you must first copy the elements somewhere else to know which ones you will want to insert, and you don't know how big to create that "somewhere else" until it's finished.  That merely moves the problem without solving it.  Your other comments are good considerations.  (Mutating the source vector is another option that works with this suggestion, but may not be an acceptible solution.)

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis Not if you use a custom iterator like OP asked for.  See my answer.

Comment: Stupid question maybe: I know that for base types it might be fast to just pass the parameter by value, and the lambda will anyway just get passed as a function since we are not capturing anything, which will probably get inlined anyway on the second pass(hopefully). But for a more complex type it would also be ok to pass const auto& val right?

Comment: @eucristian Certainly.  If the type is large, pass by `const auto&`.  I just used `auto` here because we are dealing with `int`'s and creating a reference could be more work then just making a copy.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create a custom iterator that does what you want but it is currently a little tedious to create custom iterators using standard C++. It would look something like this:

```
template <typename Itr, typename F> 
struct ConditionalIterator {
  Itr itr;
  Itr end;
  F condition;

  using value_type = typename Itr::value_type;
  using difference_type = typename Itr::difference_type;
  using pointer = typename Itr::pointer;
  using reference = typename Itr::reference;
  using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

  ConditionalIterator() = default;
  ConditionalIterator(Itr itr, Itr end, F condition): itr(itr), end(end), condition(condition) {}

  bool      operator!=(const ConditionalIterator &other) const { return other.itr != itr; }
  reference operator*() const { return *itr; }
  pointer   operator->() const { return &(*itr); }

  ConditionalIterator& operator++() {
    for (; ++itr != end;) {
      if (condition(*itr))
        break;
    }
    return *this;
  }
  ConditionalIterator operator++(int) {
    ConditionalIterator ret(*this);
    operator++();
    return ret;
  }
};
```

You can then create something like the `conditional_begin` and `conditional_end` helper functions you asked for. The only issue is that `std::vector::insert` expects the two iterators to have the same type. If we use a lambda for our condition then this will be part of the type of our conditional iterator. So we need to pass the lambda to both helper functions so that they return iterators with matching types:

```
template <typename C, typename F> 
auto conditional_begin(const C &source, F f) {
  return ConditionalIterator<typename C::const_iterator, F>(source.begin(),
                                                            source.end(), f);
}

template <typename C, typename F> 
auto conditional_end(const C &source, F f) {
  return ConditionalIterator<typename C::const_iterator, F>(source.end(),
                                                            source.end(), f);
}
```

Which you could call with a lambda like this:

```
auto condition = [](const auto &a) { return a != 3; };
target.insert(std::begin(target),
              conditional_begin(source, std::ref(condition)),
              conditional_end(source, std::ref(condition)));
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TQcHeylRY8bUYh48).

My [crude tests](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZlNSIjkTEVqLUpsK) show, in this case, this ends up being significantly faster than simply using `copy_if` and `back_inserter` because `std::vector::insert` first works out how much memory to allocate before inserting. Just using `back_inserter` will cause multiple memory allocations. The difference in performance will depend on how expensive the condition is to evaluate. You can get the same speedup by using `count_if` to reserve enough space before using `copy_if`:

```
auto count = static_cast<size_t>(std::count_if(source.begin(),
                                 source.end(), condition));
target.reserve(target.size() + count);

std::copy_if(source.begin(),
             source.end(),
             std::back_inserter(target), condition);
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ikTH5N3WPtkaRAEN).

Comment: Nice answer, +1.  I have to wonder how vector gets away with this.  An input iterator normally can only be iterated once so they must have this overloaded for other types of iterators.

Comment: I like your answer. I remember playing around with custom iterators a while ago, and it was pain. Can you explain what's the purpose of `operator++(int)`?

Comment: @KorbenDose That's the [post-increment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec). That's what gets called if you do `customItr++`. The pre-increment operator is what is called if you do `++customItr`. I added it there because I think it is supposed to be implemented for [forward iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator). Not sure if it is needed in practice though.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I think [`vector::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) is documented to have better complexity for forward iterators. I assume it uses [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to tell what type of iterator it is.

Answer (score 3):

As ranges will be standardized soon, this is an alternative using [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/), the reference library for the proprosal:

```
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>

using namespace ranges;

const std::vector<int> source{1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3};
const std::vector<int> target = view::concat(source,
    source | view::filter([](auto i){ return i != 3; }));
```

Comment: From [Herb Sutter's recent report](https://herbsutter.com/2018/07/02/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-rapperswil/): "it now looks like Ranges is “likely” to make C++20 in the next meeting or two".